# Runtime error if contact in Outlook doesn't exist

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

When I complete a piece of work I email it to certain people. It depends on the work who gets it.

If any person in the list leaves, changes job or has an email change the code will bug out saying

> Run Time error -2147467259(80004005), Outlook Does Not Recognise One Or More Names

If I manually copy the email addresses in the list and pop them into Outlook and send I'll get an email back saying the user doesn't exist or has been changed.

I have tried On Error Resume Next and On Error Goto. I have added MS Outlook 14.0 Object Libary, SharePoint Social Provider, Social Provider Extensibility and Outlook View control from the references.

The code bugs out on the .send

```
Sub EMailer()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

strfilepath = "\\DFZ70069\Data\199711009\workgroup\Res Plan Team\Performance Management\Specialised Reporting\Debit & Credit Reporting\Masters\Sent Reports\"

strArea = "Recipients" '..........................................................................................

    'Get list of recipients for email
For Each cell In Worksheets("EMails").Range(sRange)
If cell.Value = "" Then GoTo Continue
strmaillist = strmaillist & cell.Value + ";"
Continue:
Next

[B1].Value = strmaillist

If bMyEmail = True Then
strmaillist = strmaillist & MyEmailAddress
End If

    'Display email list
Dim AckTime As Integer, InfoBox As Object
Set InfoBox = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
AckTime = 1
Select Case InfoBox.Popup("Sending " & sReportName & " emails to " & vbNewLine & strArea, _
AckTime, "Message Box", 0)
Case 1, -1
End Select

    'SEND EMAIL

    'set up Body of email............
strbody = "Please find attached " & sReportName & " Report " & " _" & strDate & vbLf & vbLf & _
strComments & vbLf & _
strComments2 & vbLf & _
"" & vbLf & _
eMailName & vbLf & _
"MI & Performance Reporting Team" & vbLf & _
sline2 & vbLf & _
sline3 & vbLf & vbLf & _
sLine4

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .to = strmaillist
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = sReportName & " Report " & strDate
        .HTMLBody = "Set to HTML" & vbLf & vbLf & ""
        .Body = strbody
        .Attachments.Add (strfilepath & sTemplateName)
        .send ' bugs out here
    End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

ThisWorkbook.Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True: Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range(sRange2).Value = sConclusion '.
Application.ScreenUpdating = True: Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to check the validity of the recipient before sending, by using the `.Resolve` method of the `Recipient` object. Only valid recipients can be kept in the Recipient list of the mail item.

You might try this:

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutMail
  .Subject = sReportName & " Report " & strDate
  .HTMLBody = "Set to HTML" & vbLf & vbLf & ""
  .Body = strbody
  .Attachments.Add (strfilepath & sTemplateName)

  For Each cell In Worksheets("EMails").Range(sRange)
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
      set r = .Recipients.Add(cell.value)
      If Not r.Resolve then r.Delete '<~~ Removes invalid recipients
    End If
  Next
  .send
End With
```